# Unequal behaviour of FindRoot to two similar functions

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, equation-solving

Unfortunately, I have some difficulties to plot a function. Here is my code:

```
q1x[y_] :=0.99*(0.22237987625967498*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8))^0.9658109412817929*(E^(-(1 + y)^2/2))^0.03418905871820711*Boole[(0.5503816211315208*(E^(-(-1+ y)^2/8))^0.7928111117713841)/(E^(-(1 + y)^2/2))^0.792811111771384 > 0.3659509326398176] + 0.147861265698239*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8))^0.17299982951040888*(E^(-(1 + y)^2/2))^0.8270001704895911*Boole[(0.5503816211315208*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8))^0.7928111117713841)/(E^(-(1 + y)^2/2))^0.792811111771384 <= 0.3659509326398176])


llll[y_] :=(1.*(1.1997715598441343*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) +(0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) > 0.36887964669510726]*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])) + 0.442571309110142*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2))*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) <= 0.36887964669510726]))/(0.05313427433413315*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 +y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) >= 22.57999332595398]*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])) + 1.1997715598441343*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2))*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) +(0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) < 22.57999332595398])


tcompxx[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[llll[y]^x*q1x[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

yxcompx2[z_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[z == NIntegrate[
 llll[y]^xx*q1x[y]*Log[llll[y]], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]/tcompxx[xx], {xx, .2}]
```

I am able to evaluate

```
yxcompx2[0.4]
```

> ```
> {xx -> -0.225166}
> ```

If I change the density function `q1x[y]` to another density which is comparably complex,  then I am fine. I can obtain `yxcompx2[z]` very fast.

For example if I use `q1[y]`* (as below) instead of `q1x[y]` everything is fine!!

```
q1[y_]:= 0.99*(1.1997715598441343*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 +y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >=0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1+y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) +(0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 +y)^2/2)/2<0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) > 0.36887964669510726]*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])) + 0.442571309110142*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2))*Boole[(1.*((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 && E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >= 0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.14781756929830675*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 +y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((-1 + y)^2/8) + Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649]/(2*E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])))/((0.23838223774224732*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 <= 1.69951695056992 &&E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 >=0.789060872111649])/(E^((-1 + y)^2/8)*(E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2))^0.3906007132281111) + (0.5024369292290323*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 > 1.69951695056992])/E^((1 + y)^2/2) + (0.3147897436957645*Boole[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/8 + (1 + y)^2/2)/2 < 0.789060872111649])/E^((1 + y)^2/2)) <= 0.36887964669510726])
```

To speed up the process, I tried to use

```
opts = {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}, AccuracyGoal -> 8}
```

and `Evaluate @ opts` for the `NIntegrate` but in this case I was not able to obtain any result!

Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem? Is it possible to obtain a figure of `yxcompx2[z]`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I ask, to help get us started, whether there is some reason you expect this to be feasible? You are doing some numerical integrations, root finding, etc. -- do you think it can/could/should be done more quickly than it goes now?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't delete it just yet -- I was just hoping you had some specific mathematical reason why you expected a speed-up to be possible, so that people who know Mathematica well but don't know much about what you are doing would have a better chance of helping.

Comment: @KellenMyers I updated the question. Now it is much simpler. The problem is at equation solving, namely at findroot part. I have no idea why is this happening. I also put a more complex density function $q_1$. If one replaces $q1x$ with $q1$ in all definitions, then everything works fine. I expect to speed up the process because, a more complex form creates a result very fast although a simpler form cannot.

Comment: That looks much better -- unfortunately this isn't my best area of expertise, and I don't have enough time to hack something out for you, but the question looks much better, more likely to get a useful response. I hope someone can help!